# Biblatex-chicago: \fullcite flips first and last name

Tags: biblatex, citing, chicago-style

I'm writing an annotated bibliography which requires full in-line citations in Chicago format. However, when I use biblatex-chicago and \fullcite to list the full citation, it varies from the reference format used in the bibliography. Specifically, the author's name is presented First M Last instead of Last, First M. The rest of the citation is fine. Any ideas why this might be and/or how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,numbermonth=false,doi=false,%
            isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{<bibfilename>.bib}
\begin{document}
Here comes the full citation that I will be using:

\fullcite{<key>}

It looks different from the reference that you will see below,%
as the first and last name are reversed.
\printbibliography
```

I have tried other advice regarding customization of \fullcite but most other articles deal with a different biblatex format such as APA. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The information in the bib file is parsed in to separate fields that hold e.g. the first name and the last name.  Writing Last, First M. in the bib file is an excellent way to help biber with that parsing.  How this is output in the final file is then up to the given bibliography style file.

Answer (score 12):

The `authordate` style from `biblatex-chicago` uses the standard definition of `\fullcite` from `biblatex.def`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

`\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}` sets the `sortname` list in the default `first-last` format. Deleting this bit of code will give the same format as the bibliography. So you can add the following re-definition to your preamble:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```