# Excessive fields in biblatex could not be removed if using \fullcite

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

Combination of `biblatex-chicago` and Zotero produces many excessive fileds in the bibliography. This problem could be solved by adding to the preambule caveats like this:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{online}
{}
{\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}
```

(Described in detail in the answer to my previous question: [Excessive fields in biblatex chicago author-date style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147749/excessive-fields-in-biblatex-chicago-author-date-style).)

This solution worked well for me, but now I have to produce a syllabus using `\fullcite` command. Unfortunately, this solution does not solve the problem for full bibliographic entries outside of the bibliography itself.

Here is the code with bibliography inside (to get the author's first and last name in the right order I use the following solution: [Biblatex-chicago: \fullcite flips first and last name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85305/biblatex-chicago-fullcite-flips-first-and-last-name)):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
    @book{dalton_apartisan_2012,
        title = {The Apartisan American: Dealignment and Changing Electoral Politics},
        isbn = {9781452216942},
        url = {http://books.google.com/books?id=eYkczUyX5wMC},
        shorttitle = {The Apartisan American},
        pagetotal = {241},
        publisher = {{CQ} Press},
        author = {Dalton, Russell J.},
        urldate = {2014-04-03},
        date = {2012-02-22},
        langid = {english},
        keywords = {Political Science / Political Process / Elections, Political Science / Public Policy / General}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{cancel,soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,bookpages=false,doi=only,isbn=false,footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[colorlinks, pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.25},bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=\maxdimen,citecolor={blue},urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{database.bib}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usedriver
    {}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{article}\OR\ifentrytype{book}\OR\ifentrytype{collection}\OR\ifentrytype{incollection}\OR\ifentrytype{mvbook}\OR\ifentrytype{mvcollection}\OR\ifentrytype{mvincollection}}
    {\clearfield{month}\clearfield{url}\clearfield{doi}\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\huge Partisanship in Old, New and Non-Democracies}\\
\end{center}

\vspace{30pt}
\noindent\textbf{Instructor: }  \hfill
\textbf{Time and Location:} TBA\\
\textbf{Contact:} 
\hfill
\hfil \textbf{Office Hours:} TBA\\

\vspace{-20pt}



\subsection*{Partisanship in the United States}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item \parencite{dalton_apartisan_2012}
    \item \fullcite{dalton_apartisan_2012}
\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Here is the output. Note the excessive fileds in the in-text full citation (they are absent in the References):

[image]

Any help, especially simple acessible solutions would be greatlly apreciated.

Comment: There's an `\AtEveryCite` as well as an `\AtEveryCitekey` in `biblatex`.

Comment: In addition to jon's suggestion, you could still map all these fields to null using sourcemapping.

Comment: As @moewe says, the best way to do this is to do this as early as possible before biblatex even sees the data, using the biber sourcemapping feature. There are many examples of this on TSE.

Comment: @jon: OK, so I tried to add to my `\AtEveryBibitem` code exactly the same code but starting with `\AtEveryCitekey` and it resolves the issue, but produces the following mess in front of every citation: "blx@hook@citekey@next" (like (blx@hook@citekey@nextDalton 2012). (Also I am curious why you have to include both? And you have to, because if only code starting with `\AtEveryCitekey`is included, the thing doesn't compile at all. Here they also use both: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40097/disable-issn-but-keep-isbn-with-biblatex]).

Comment: @moewe and PLK, I looked up souremapping in biber manual and, unfortunately, it's beyond by proficiency level in biblatex.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to control the `urldate` in bibliography and citations independently, `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\AtEveryCitekey` are the way to go.

`\AtEveryBibitem` performs its actions at every item in the bibliography, while `\AtEveryCitekey` performs its actions at every item cited. (See pp. 228-229 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

So to get rid of, say, the `title` only in citations, you would go with `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}` - the `title` is then ignored in citations, but still printed in the bibliography. Analogously, `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}` gets rid of the URL date only on the bibliography, not in the citations.

In order to get rid of the URL date everywhere, you could therefore issue

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}
```

Type restrictions can be applied by `\ifentrytype` or even more complex constructs like so

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {}
    {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} or test {\ifentrytype{book}}}
    {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}
    {}}
```

The first example deletes the URL date for all but `@online` entries, while the second deletes them only for `@article` and `@book`.

---

For technical reasons (I could think of possible label date creation) it is better though to get rid of the URL date as early as possible, if you don't want to use it at all. Here Biber's sourcemapping comes in (see §4.5.2 *Dynamic Modification of Data*, pp. 148-156 of [the doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

We want to get rid of the `urldate` field in your `.bib` file, so we just set it to `null`.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}
```

With sourcemapping, type restrictions can be imposed by `\pertype` like so

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This map now only applies to `@article`s and `@book`s.
Sadly, with `\pertype` one cannot use negations as we did above (as in "only apply this to entries that are not `@online`"), maybe that's worth a feature request (- it was worth one and [our wish has been granted](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/299)).

Since the date field is a bit special in how it's handled by `biblatex`. In the document it is available as three fields `year`, `month` and `day` (so one could use `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}` without any trouble), for source-mapping purposes (remember, source-mapping is one of the first steps Biber takes with a file, at this point nothing has been interpreted or read from the file) often the date is input as `date = {YYYY-MM-DD}`, that is why just deleting the `month` field in source-mapping will only help those who input the date as  `year = {2014}, month = {03}, day={04}` (which is possible, but slightly less comfortable).
What we can do though is, we can make the date year-only with RegEx

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=month, null]
      \step[fieldsource=date,
            match=\regexp{([0-9]{4})-[0-9]{2}(-[0-9]{2})*},
            replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

We look for a string of the form "YYYY-MM-DD" or possibly just "YYYY-MM-DD" and just retain the "YYYY" part, thus retaining only the year.
We also set the month to `null` for those who prefer to input the date more verbosely.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,mergedate=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{online}
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=month, null]
      \step[fieldsource=date,
            match=\regexp{([0-9]{4})-[0-9]{2}(-[0-9]{2})*},
            replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{baez/online,itzhaki,markey}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Gives

[image]

Below is the output without any source-mapping for comparison

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your second solution worked! I just want to clarify for other users how to make it work for more complex purposes and also why I was not able to make your first solution work for my purposes.
`\AtEveryCitekey` (unlike, `\AtEveryBibitem`) was not able to swallow `\ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{...}}`clauses. Since in most cases I need to delete particular fields for particular types of entries, this did not work for me.

Comment: Sourcemapping solves this problem, but (compared to `\AtEveryBibitem`) the syntax to specify entry types and fields is a bit different: for both purposes you just need to add a new line. For example to delete both `url`/`doi` and `urldate` for both books and articles you have to write the following:
`\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
   \pertype{article}
   \pertype{book}
   \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
   \step[fieldset=url, null]
   \step[fieldset=doi, null]
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @homo_loquens Both `\AtEveryCitekey` and `\AtEveryBibitem` support `\ifentrytype` and even more complex conditional constructions, the error you mentioned in your other comments looks suspiciously like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229528/35864).

Comment: yes, right you are, in my case the whole misunderstanding came from my improper modification of your elegant solution [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147749/excessive-fields-in-biblatex-chicago-author-date-style), where you had `then` rather than `else` part empty. I think `\AtEveryBibitem` was just less vulnerable to my erratic syntax and worked where `\AtEveryCitekey` failed.

Comment: One last clarification: I have a problem with the field `month` (which, if not removed, produces a date, say, September 20, for both books and articles). Both `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\AtEveryCitekey` remove it easily like any other field (`doi` or `url`, for example). Sourcemapping though has no effect on it. (Note that we are taking about date of publication here, not date of access/`urldate`. Date is specified in .bib file as in my example: YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: @homo_loquens That's due to the special format date fields have, for source-mapping purposes a date specified as `date = {YYYY-MM-DD}` is just a date field, while for `biblatex` styles the date splits into `year`, `month` and `date`, so you can only selectively get rid of `months` by dropping them later (or by using regex in the source-mapping).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! If you would feel like that, it would be great to see the sketch of this regex source-mapping (or even better if you make it part of your MWE). But if it would help nobody but me, I can just use `AtEveryCitekey`.

Comment: @homo_loquens Have a look at the modified answer, it now features a get-rid-of-all-date-parts-but-the-year-source-mapping.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! One thing I don't get though, is what to do with the $ sign in the replace part - it renders the whole subsequent code as in math mode.

Comment: @homo_loquens Mhh, it shouldn't `$1` is a place-holder for the first match, which in our case is going to be the year. Maybe you are using an older version of `biblatex`/Biber. Did you try the actual MWE above and did get this strange behaviour?

Comment: I did try it, but in my new editor, TeXstudio. However in Winedt everything works properly, so it's probably TeXstudio problem. I will leave them a ticket.

Comment: @homo_loquens That is very odd indeed. This code should not (and to my knowledge does not) depend on the editor at all.

Comment: FYI http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1155/ (my ticket was closed and redirected to this)

Comment: @homo_loquens So it was entirely a syntax-highlighting and not a `biblatex`/Biber or actual output problem problem?

Comment: Yes, but it is also important. Actually their solution does not fix all the problems, such as folding preamble.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution from @moewe worked for me (even for `\fullcite`), but I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175534/173645) a shorter solution:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\UseBibitemHook}
```