# Omit data from the bib file in citation, but show it in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing, urls

I’d like to cite a website including its name, maintainer and URL, but not the access date, in a footnote.

Using the `\fullcite` command, the whole entry appears in the footnote as well as in the bibliography.
Is there a way to keep the access date in the bib file, so that it appears in the bibliography, but to omit it in the citation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@online{doe2015,
        title = {My Website},
        url = {https://website.org},
        author = {Doe, John},
        urldate = {2015-09-17},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
The fullcite command in a footnote:\footnote{For reference see \fullcite{doe2015}.}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you really using `\ref`? Because you should use `\cite`. Can you add a bit more about what style you are using etc. A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) is a good way to tell us that.

Comment: @moewe
I wrote this question in a hurry. Sorry for any inconvenience I might have caused. I’ll correct it and write an MWE later today.

Comment: @moewe I have specified the question and inserted an MWE. It should be much clearer now.

Comment: So you are using the default `numeric` style? And you only want to suppress the `urldate` in a `\fullcite`? In that case try `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{urlyear}}`.

Comment: See also [Excessive fields in biblatex could not be removed if using \fullcite](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864)

Comment: @moewe At the moment, I’m using the style *authoryear*, but haven’t finally decided yet: this is because I use many CJK sources. In addition, I have to conform to formal conventions of the liberal arts used in Germany. I’m still figuring out the best way to do this. With all this in mind, the MWE would not be so M, and maybe not W... So I decided to keep it as simple as possible by removing all the localization and special requirements.

Comment: @moewe Your answer is of course correct, and has been discussed here before. I didn’t find the solution by myself because I wasn’t looking for the right search terms.

Comment: OK, you see sometimes (very often, actually) the solution depends on the style. In this case it doesn't. Anyway, is your question answered with the duplicate? If so, I will vote to close this question here as a duplicate.

Comment: That fully answers my question. Thanks for your effort here, and there as well! Pleas vote to close.

Comment: OK! I will vote to close, then.