# Hide certain fields when citing

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I am using biblatex with biber as backend. In my .bib file, I use some additional fields like `titleaddon`, `usere` etc., which should be displayed within the printed bibliography. However, when using `\cite`, `\footcite` etc., these additional fields should be hidden. Is there a possibility to overwrite the define the to be displayed fields for certain entry types or even all entry types? So far, I only found a solution to hide certain fields within the bibliography, but this is not what I desire. Thank you very much for your efforts!

Comment: `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{foo}\clearlist{bar}}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233581/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268071/35864

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested your proposed solution and it works. This question can be marked as duplicate.  I did not find the linked questions previously, maybe I searched for the wrong keywords.

Comment: Well, it is always easier to find duplicate questions if you also know the answer.