# How to use \Cite in sidenotes without printing the URL?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using `biblatex-chicago-notes` in combination with the `sidenotes` package. For my current project I am using quite a lot of online articles with an `URL` field. The use of `\Cite` prints the `URL` not only in the bibliography but also in the text margin. In order to save space and improve the clarity I would like to omit the `URL` field in the margins but *not* in the bibliography (otherwise, I could have used `url=false` in the preamble). All current citation commands in `biblatex-chicago` do not fullfill that need. How can this be achieved?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article:poole2001,
author          = {Poole, Steven},
title           = {Trigger Happy: Videogames and the Entertainment Revolution},
date            = {2008-01-15},
abstract        = {2001 edition, with 2004 afterword},
url             = {http://stevenpoole.net/blog/trigger-happier/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum.\sidenote{\Cite{{article:poole2001}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: An easy work-around is `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{urlyear}}`. See also [Excessive fields in biblatex could not be removed if using \fullcite](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864).

Comment: This works as intended except for the »leftover« comma at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{urlyear}}
```

to get rid of the URL and `urldate` in citations as explained in [Excessive fields in biblatex could not be removed if using \fullcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864).

With `chicago-notes` that leaves a spurious comma, however, this is due to the macro `cjournal+issue+year+pages` not using `\setunit`s in certain places. To fix that we need

```
\renewbibmacro*{cjournal+issue+year+pages}{%
  \usebibmacro{cjournal+ser+vol+num}%
  \ifboolexpr{% 16th ed.
    test {\iffieldundef{issue}}%
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{year}}%
    and
    not togl {cms@switchdates}%
  }%
  {\iffieldundef{number}%
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{pagination}\AND%
        \iffieldundef{bookpagination}}%
      {\setunit{\postvolpunct}}%
      {\setunit{\addcolon\addspace}}}%
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}}%<---- here
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{volume}\AND\iffieldundef{number}}% 16th ed.
    {\newcunit%
      \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{number+or+month}}%
      {\printfield{issue}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cmsyear}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}%<--- here
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{% parens is the default here
      \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{number+or+month}}%
      {\printfield{issue}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cmsyear}}}}}}
```

Where we wrapped the `\addcomma\addspace` in the indicated lines in `\setunit`s.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=5cm, 
            margin=6cm,
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article:poole2001,
author          = {Poole, Steven},
title           = {Trigger Happy: Videogames and the Entertainment Revolution},
date            = {2008-01-15},
abstract        = {2001 edition, with 2004 afterword},
url             = {http://stevenpoole.net/blog/trigger-happier/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{urlyear}}

\renewbibmacro*{cjournal+issue+year+pages}{%
  \usebibmacro{cjournal+ser+vol+num}%
  \ifboolexpr{% 16th ed.
    test {\iffieldundef{issue}}%
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{year}}%
    and
    not togl {cms@switchdates}%
  }%
  {\iffieldundef{number}%
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{pagination}\AND%
        \iffieldundef{bookpagination}}%
      {\setunit{\postvolpunct}}%
      {\setunit{\addcolon\addspace}}}%
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}}%<---- here
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{volume}\AND\iffieldundef{number}}% 16th ed.
    {\newcunit%
      \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{number+or+month}}%
      {\printfield{issue}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cmsyear}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}%<--- here
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{% parens is the default here
      \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{number+or+month}}%
      {\printfield{issue}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cmsyear}}}}}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum.\sidenote{\Cite{article:poole2001}}

Dolor\sidenote{\Cite{sigfridsson}}

\end{document}
```

[image]