# Clear urldate field manually

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

There is a bug in biblatex-chicago package.

Biblatex-chicago prints the urldate information ("accessed September 27,
2017.") even if "`url=false`" is specified
(`\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex-chicago}`).

This is not the behavior of biblatex.

I informed the author who will fix it. **In the meantime, I need a way to clear the urldate field which touching my .bib database.**

I tried without success:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urldate}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,url=false]{biblatex-chicago}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test_biblio.bib}
\begin{document}

text
\autocite{test42}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

test_biblio.bib

```
@book{test42,
  author = {Author},
  title = {title},
  year = 2001,
  title = {Title},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate = {2017-09-27}
}
```

Comment: `\clearfield{urlyear}`

Comment: The problem is that `urldate` is split up into its components and as such for `biblatex` internally only `urlyear`, `urlmonth`, `urlmonth` exist, even though the input only uses `urldate`.

Comment: See also [Excessive fields in biblatex could not be removed if using \fullcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864)

Comment: @moewe ok `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}` works. It was "year" and not "date", stupid me... Turn this into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, `date`-like fields are decomposed by the backend (Biber or BibTeX) into their dateparts for easier handling within `biblatex`. So for `biblatex` there is no such thing as `urldate`, but there are `urlyear`, `urlmonth`, `urlday`, ... (Of course this does not mean that `urldate` should not be used as input in the `.bib` file, in fact only `urldate` is valid input, `urlyear` is not.)

So you need to delete the dateparts. Since `biblatex` doesn't print a date, if its year is missing, it is enough to say

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}}
```

If you don't want the `urldate` at all,

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}
```

is safer because it makes sure that the `urldate` is completely ignored, whereas even if you use `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}}` it can be used for label generation.