Surpressing the urldate for specific bibliographic entry types
How can the urldate being surpressed for specific entry types, e.g. articles? In my bib file, there is an urldate field entry entered for every article (and there are a lot of), but I need to "remove" this from the bibliography without going the complicated way of actually removing that entry in each article. So I'd like to use the easy way by just surpressing this field for articles.
Any suggestions?
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes,hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{test,
  title={Testing Title},
  author={Testperson, Some},
  year={2024},
  publisher={Some Publisher},
  location = {Anywhere},
  doi={10.123234/dkjslfdkj},
  urldate={2023-02-19},
}
@online{test2,
  title={Second Testing Title},
  author={Testperson, Any},
  year={2024},
  publisher={Some Publisher},
  location = {Anywhere},
  url={www.test.com},
  urldate={2023-02-19},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    date=year,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
    urldate=long,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}


Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864 help?

The style combination style=apa, bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, is equivalent to style=authoryear-ibid, (which is much shorter and far less confusing).

@moewe Yes, that helped a lot! Thank you very much!!
